# Excel PivotTable Date Grouping in 24-hr Center

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, date

I am attempting to analyze data of agents working in my company that runs 24/7. I was going to construct a pivot table to show the daily operations of each individual. This fit most of my needs however, being a 24-hour business, some agents work overnight (ie. 8pm-4am), and this is causing the data to be inaccurate when viewing those members by day as it includes half of 2 shifts rather than their whole shift. The data I have has the time/day listed for each action the agent has taken over a period of time. Any assistance to properly group the dates would be very much appreciated.

[image: Picture for some data reference]

Comment: Data in the attached screen shot is quite confusing,, 1st I guess the second column is Start Data Time,, and the last one especially that how you are getting state duration, for example difference of time 87 is what Minutes/ Hours, also date time must have AM/PM ,,please [edit] your post & upload data in correct format,, help us to fix the issue. And are U looking to get group for both Day & Night shift ?

Comment: To clarify:
Times are using 24-hr format; 

StatusDateTime is when they entered that status; 

StatusKey is the status they are in; 

EndDateTime is when they left the status; 

State Duration is the duration of that status in seconds; 

What I am doing is gathering time users are in different statuses and organizing it into a pivot table. This is fairly straightforward to do but the agents that work past midnight are not properly shown in the pivot table since it is grouped by day and 1 of their shifts is technically spread across 2 days. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Brian Silva,, could U plz tell me that how U got 87 for Row no 2 where time is 06/22/2020 06:07 and End time is 06/22/2020 06:08,,, as U told duration is in seconds ,,, since the time difference is 1 minute then how U r getting 87 Seconds? Read my data below where,, when is night shift the DATE is changing !!

Comment: ,,, **Cont,,,** no where in your database past midnight date time is included in both columns DATEs are similar only the TIMe is changing !! Pivot Table uses data from SOURCE only.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm sure that you are looking for this only:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter Start & End Date and Time using,  `mm/dd/yy h:mm AM/PM` cell format.

*You may alter `Date & Time format` according to practice in your zone.*

- Formula in cell U2 & applied format is `HH:MM`.

  `=T2-R2`
- The formula in cell V2 determines the Working Shift, helps to categories data accordingly while creating Pivot Table.

  ```
  =LOOKUP(HOUR(R2),{0,12,16},{"Morning","Afternoon","Night"})&" Shift"
  ```

**N.B.**

- *While creating Pivot Table, put Agents in ROWS, Shift Details in COLUMNS and Duration in VALUE (use COUNT).*
- I've skipped the column Work Status/Key, if you feel you may include
  it also.

Comment: While this could be useful for determining the shifts they work, my issue is more underlying. What I am doing is gathering time users are in different statuses and organizing it into a pivot table. This is fairly straightforward to do but the agents that work past midnight are not properly shown in the pivot table since it is grouped by day and 1 of their shifts is technically spread across 2 days. Any ideas?